# Search from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

This is a code which is working fine without any error giving result.

```
SELECT student.id, student.name, fee_slip.payamount, fee_slip.time, student.class
FROM student
LEFT JOIN fee_slip
ON student.id=fee_slip.student
where (fee_slip.student) is null
```

But now I want to make it more dynamic.

I have a code which is also working good but I am using it on a single table.

```
$query = "SELECT  id, name,  std_reg_number, class, section  FROM student  where id IS NOT NULL ";

if ($name != "") {
    $query .= " AND `name` LIKE '" . $name . "%'"; // id is greater then
}

if ($status != "") {
    $query .= " AND `status` LIKE '" . $status . "%'"; // id is greater then
}

if ($class != "") {
    $query .= " AND class IN($class) ORDER BY class DESC"; // Selecting class
}

if ($section != "") {
    $query .= " AND section IN($section)"; // selecting section
}

if ($sort != "") {
    $query .= " ORDER BY $sort ASC"; // Selecting religion
}

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Now I tried to use subquery

```
$query .= " SELECT  fee_slip.student_id,  fee_slip.std_reg_number, fee_slip.payamount, fee_slip.totalamount ";
```

But I didn't get results.

What should I do?

Comment: The first thing you should do is... stop using the deprecated mysql interface, and use mysqli or PDO instead.  The second thing you should do is stop creating SQL Injection vulnerabilities by incorporating potentially unsafe values in the SQL text, by either properly escaping the values (for example, by using mysqli_real_escape_string), or by using prepared statements with bind placeholders.

Comment: I'm not understanding the relationship between the query shown at the beginning of the question, and the code that's shown. We see the code is dynamically creating SQL text (vulnerable to SQL Injection), and executing the query. Then, we see SQL being *appended* to the existing SQL text. It's *not* possible to execute two different SELECT statements in a single execution using the mysql interface. (One approach is to combine the results from two queries using `UNION ALL` (the columns have to line up, count and dataype, and add a discriminator column), so it's just one statement.

Comment: After union all can I achieve what I need

Comment: @SunilSorout please mark an answer . It will help others. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between the terms "[subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subqueries.html)" and "[multi-query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)". You seem to be mixing those concepts up.

Assuming the query you posted works the way you need it to, it seems you could just replace the `$query` value in the code with that, and it would work just as well as the query you have there now. (You might have to add the table names/aliases to the fields in the WHERE clauses though, to avoid ambiguity. Depends on your table structure.)

In any case, adding another SELECT after the query you have now isn't the way to go.

I would also, like others have before me, point out that the old MySQL API functions are outdated, and that your code is riddled with security issues. - Prepared Statements through either PDO or MySQLi should be used these days.

Comment: So how to achieve that